# Xamarin wont deploy to Android emulator no errors

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and ran into immediate trouble while doing a basic Hello World example. When I click Debug, the Android emulator starts but never finishes even after 20 minutes. The emulator just sits on a black screen. I never see the Android boot sequence. I can build the solution with no errors. I can also open the emulator by itself through AVD without any errors. My laptop is VS 2017 Community, Win10 Fall Creator, i5-6200, 8GB RAM, GeForce 940M, and 50GB free on SSD. I have tried:

1. Reinstalling VS
2. Reinstalling Java SDK and Android
3. Updating Android SDK packages
4. Changing registry location of SDK
5. Turning off Fast Deploy
6. Creating new AVD's

Comment: what happens if you boot the emulator FIRST, then try to deploy from VS?

Comment: The emulator loads and I can interact with it (open apps). When I click debug the emulator appears to relaunch and stays on a black screen. No errors.

Comment: What is your android emulator architecture ? `x86` or `arm` ?

Comment: I think I have narrowed the issue. Up to this point I have been using Oreo emulator and my project compilation was set to "Use Latest Platform Oreo. On a hunch, I tried switching everything to Nougat and it worked. By the way, I am using x86 emulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting many hours on this, I finally can across the answer. You can't use the standard AVD and SDK managers. Google removed support for them after SDK Tools version 26.0.1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/

If you need to make an Oreo 8.0 or 8.1 emulator, install [Xamarin Android SDK Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager). Caution, this will prevent you from using the built-in AVD and SDK managers. From then on, you will use this new SDK manager and the command line to create and launch AVD's.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your SDK's its under Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me before, i did reinstall only to find out it was the emulator issue. to avoid yourself in reinstalling the visual studio and save you time... you can try it on your actual android device. then let me know how it goes. hope it helps.